# Is it better to filter before joining when the tables are very huge?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have customer table and sales table with millions of records.

To find sales belonging to CustomerA, supppse I write query like below:

```
Select *
From customer c
Join sales s
In c.custid=S.custid
Where c.custname='customerA'
```

The logical order of execution is:
JOIN, WHERE, SELECT.

Does this mean that all records of customer and sales with be fetched and joined. And then records will be filtered based on the customer name? If so then is it more performant to write the following:

```
Select * 
From (select * FROM customer ci where customername='customerA') c
Join sales s
On c.customerid=S.customerid
```

Comment: It is generally best to allow the optimiser to choose the most efficient path. In my experience, you should only attempt to force the optimiser down a particular path in circumstances where you have special knowledge concerning the data.

Comment: Ok so generally I need to worry about this only when optimizer cannot look at the statistics on the server. For example - a query where one table is on the local server and the other table is on a linked server?

Comment: Remember that SQL (at least in SQL Server) is _declarative_ - in that what you 'tell' it to do may not be how it eventually does it. You will often find that rewriting a query to have sub-queries, CTEs etc may not actually change the execution plan, or change it much. It's better in most cases to write _simple_ SQL which the query optimiser to choose the best options. However, there are times it has problems (usually in bad estimation of rows with complex SQL) - one solution for this is to run part of the query and store in a #temporary table, then use that temp table in the second part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WHERE and JOIN clauses order performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304855/where-and-join-clauses-order-performance) Although that was talking about Postgres, every single word of it applies here. The particular subquery you are trying won't work in the way you intend anyway, the optimizer isn't *that* stupid

Comment: "The logical order of execution is: JOIN, WHERE, SELECT. Does this mean that all records of customer and sales with be fetched and joined" - No. This is the **logical** order - not some fixed physical ordering